# Bridging VSTO to Office.js functionality

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-js

I have created an Office plugin using Office JS and React Fabric, that runs in Word, Excel, and PowerPoint. It is a relatively simple plug-in which consists of a context menu and a ribbon button in the Home tab that both trigger a task pane.

However, in desktop versions of Office 2016, as well as earlier versions like Office 2013, the plugin task pane works, but there is no icon shown in the ribbon. Nor is there a context menu.

As I understand it, this is not a bug in my manifest, but the expected functionality on earlier versions of Word, Excel and PowerPoint in Office, because they [do not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability) [add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands).

Given that, I'm trying to understand the shortest route to supporting these earlier versions. Presumably that is to create a VSTO plugin for each platform I'd like to support. Ideally, I'd like that VSTO plugin to simply add the context menu and ribbon buttons, but then delegate the actual task pane to the existing Office.js add-in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> ...As I understand it, this is not a bug in my manifest, but the
>   expected functionality on earlier versions of Word, Excel and
>   PowerPoint in Office, because they do not support add-in commands.

Your statement above is 100% correct.

> Ideally, I'd like that VSTO plugin to simply add the context menu and
>   ribbon buttons, but then delegate the actual task pane to the existing
>   Office.js add-in. Is this possible?

What you suggest in theory is possible, but that would be re-writing the modern add-in framework and even then your modern add-ins wouldn't work as-is because you'll have to do all kinds of API mappings from COM to JS. If you want to go as far as 2010, you only have the option of doing VSTO I'm afraid.

Comment: What if I just want to support 2016, but include people who don't have Office 365 subscriptions?

Comment: Then it's a different story. 2016 splits into two, the one that comes with the subscription and the one that's perpetual. They both support the modern framework, with the only difference being 2016 perpetual will upgrade much slower and stop at some stage, which means if you're using the latest APIs (which only ship with subscription one), even 2016 perpetual folks will get those functionalities much later and therefore can't use the addin. If you're using something simple though (check out the requirement sets) which even 2013 supports, then you're fine

Comment: I'm not using any fancy APIs... I just want to display a toolbar icon and a context menu. Per my experimentation, Office 2016 perpetual doesn't seem to support even this, at least as of the current updates. If you follow the link I included in the question, the MS docs weren't even clear about this: I had to create a GitHub issue to request docs clarifications: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/906.

Comment: What do you mean by context menu? If you're talking about the ribbon buttons, 2016 perpetual definitely supports it.

Comment: No, in 2016 perpetual the add-in shows up in the ribbon as a drop-down under "My add-ins" (which is useless as no user will ever see it here). In my local test I found its not possible to create a separate ribbon button (and this is confirmed by MS as per the GitHub issue above). By context menu, I mean the menu that shows up when you select text in Word, and then right-click. Adding an option to this menu doesn't work in 2016 Perpetual either.

Comment: @Raman I'd appreciate the green tick if this qualifies as an answer...